# Google My Business API to fetch Reviews

Tags: c#, google-my-business-api

I want to know how can I use GMB API to fetch reviews.  According to google documentation we have to make a GET request to `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/{name=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews`

But what is meant by `{name=accounts/*/locations/*}` and from where we can get the value of accounts & locations.

Also this requires OAuth 2.0.  If I get a access_token then GET request will be like this:-
`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/{name=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews?access_token=token`

This is very confusing.  Can somebody tell me how to use GMB API correctly to fetch google reviews.

Comment: Have you read through any and all of the documentation on the `Google` website in relation to the `My Business API`

Comment: Did you find any solution? @puneet

Answer (score 5):

Using Google OAuth 2 Playground
For testing acquisition of Google reviews

1. Create a project

   - Console.cloud.google.com
   - Sign in as {projectowner}@google.com
   - Select a project from the dropdown in the header or click new project
2. Go to APIs & Services in the left menu
3. Enable the Google My Business API; this requires validation by Google and may take a couple of days. They will email you.
4. Go to developers.google.com/oauthplayground
5. Using the settings gear, set OAuth flow to Client-side and click Use your own OAuth credentials
6. Get the client id from console.developers.google.com/apis and paste it in
7. Put this into scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage and authorize it with {projectowner}@gmail.com
8. Exchange auth code for token
9. To get the account name:

   - Set Request URI to https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts and send a Get request
   - Copy the entire string value at “name”: not including quotes; it may be 20+ numeric digits
10. To get location names:

    - Set Request URI to https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{paste account name here}/locations where {paste ... here} is the account name you copied
    - The returned JSON contains all of your locations
    - Copy the location names including quotes and commas to a temporary holding document; they will be used in a JSON array in the next step
11. To get multiple locations’ reviews
    a.  Set Request URI to https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{account name here}/locations:batchGetReviews and the Method to Post
    b.  Set Request Body to 
    {
    "locationNames": [
    "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/88888888888888888888",
    "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/77777777777777777777",
    .
    .
    .
    "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/11111111111111111111"
    ],
    "pageSize": 200,
    "orderBy": "updateTime desc",
    "ignoreRatingOnlyReviews": false
    }

using the account names you saved from the location JSON for each line of the array

12. If you have more than 200 total reviews you will have to add "pageToken": string into the JSON body where string is a value returned in the preceding POST.

Comment: why do i got a permission denied? I followed everything and I stacked at step 9 because of permission denied

Comment: When you were in the OAuth 2.0 Playground did you put  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage into the scope AND HIT ENTER, followed by clicking Authorize APIs? After you paste in the URI you must hit enter for the Authorize button to be enabled.

Comment: Tried creating a post using this endpoint `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/localPosts` and it returns me an `Requested entity was not found.` any suggestions?

Comment: Did you copy the "name:" value returned in step 9 and paste it into the URI in place of {account name here}? 
[link](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{account name here}/locations:batchGetReviews)    Also, you need to set the body to `{ "locationNames": [ "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/88888888888888888888", "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/77777777777777777777", . . . "accounts/999999999999999999999/locations/11111111111111111111" ], "pageSize": 200, "orderBy": "updateTime desc", "ignoreRatingOnlyReviews": false }` where you replace the numbers with yours.

Comment: i only use the account number which is `account_name/8123127` sir

Comment: i have google auth 2.0 key client key and secret i am try to access on the postman but not work

https://www.postman.com/galactic-capsule-938676/workspace/gmb-api/documentation/14098576-9a7bf6ff-0283-4d1c-b06b-143bae158929

 i change the value but still getting   "error": {
        "code": 401,

Answer (score 0):

> But what is meant by {name=accounts/*/locations/*} and from where we can get the value of accounts & locations.

To get this details first get the account using the following API (`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=#####`)

Once you have the account list, fetch Account Location list using the following API (`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/" + name + "/locations`) in the response of this API you will get the `{name=accounts/*/locations/*}`.

> Also this requires OAuth 2.0. If I get a access_token then GET request will be like this: `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/{name=accounts/*/locations/*}/reviews?access_token=token`

Yes, that is correct.

Let me know if this work's for you.